# Exponential Function and simultaneous equations

Tags: exponential-function

I have this maths problem for school that I cannot solve.

$a(x) = Ne^{kx}$
This exponential function can be calculated by looking at the maximum height of each bounce.
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
              \hline   &   \rm First\: Bounce     &     \rm Second\: Bounce   &   \rm  Third\: bounce\\\hline
  \rm  Max\: Height   &      -0.277        &           -0.350     &         -0.410\\\hline
  \rm  Time         &       0.85         &            1.30      &           1.65\\
\hline\end{array}$$

Use these points to create simultaneous equations of the form $a(x) = Ne^{kx}$, where $N$ represents the maximum height and $k$ represents the corresponding time.

So basically I have to graph the 3 quadratic equations of the 3 bounces of the ball using a combined equation: $Ne^{kx} |\sin(b(x-c))|+d$

The equation $f(x)=|a \sin(b(x-c))|+d$ was used to graph the duration of the 3 bounces. While the $Ne^{kx}$ is supposed to vary the height of each bounce accordingly.

Comment: is $N>0$ or how can an exponential function be negative?

Comment: A ball was dropped from point '0' and it landed on the ground at -0.524m. Meaning the height of the drop was 52.4cm. The ball then bounced up to -0.277m, meaning it bounced up 0.247m.

Comment: It seems to me that you should find a new displacement of the height, perhaps using that $f_{max}=a+d$?

Comment: Thanks for your consideration. I am not too sure about that either, on the question it does not state which to use. Sorry